# Display sub menu with django cms

Tags: django, django-cms

I try to display sub menu with the tag "show_sub_menu".
I have many sub menus :

- Menu1

  - sub menu1
  - sub menu2
- Menu2

  - sub menu3
  - sub menu4
    ...

If I am on a page contained in menu1 or its sub-menus, I want to display a list with :

- sub menu1
- sub menu2

If I am on a page contained in menu2 or its sub-menus, I want to display a list with :

- sub menu3
- sub menu4

So, I created a new template :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags %}


{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            {% placeholder "content" %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            {% show_sub_menu 1 %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

It's works when I open in the page Menu1 or Menu2 but not when I open the pages "sub menu*".
I try with : `{% show_sub_menu 0 %}` or `{% show_sub_menu -1 %}`
but it doesn't work, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Can you show your views and template tags?

Comment: I didn't have dedicated views for this topic. I use Page module from django-cms,  for the template tags it's the same it's provided by djangocms.

Answer (score 0):

If you do {% show_menu 0 1 0 1 menu.html %}
and have to make changes to menu.html. menu.html should be inside the template/menu

```
{% for child in children %}
<li class="nav-item">
<a hre="{{child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url}}"> {{child.get_menu_title}} </a>
{% if child.children %}
<ul class = "sub_menu">
{% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template ' ' ' ' child %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```